# What have I done wrong in my APP_CONFIG yml file in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3.1.1. This is my YAML file in `config/app_config.yml`

```
development: &non_production_settings
  site_url: http://localhost:3000
```

This is my stripped `config/application.rb`

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# load app_config.yml  
require 'yaml'  
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app_config.yml', __FILE__)))

require 'rails/all'
```

I tried to put `site_url` in my template, even abort it, but it's still returning nil:

```
<%= abort(APP_CONFIG[:site_url]) %> #returns: can't convert nil into String
```

What have I done wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to move the code a bit and add an environment to it:

```
# config/application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# load app_config.yml  
require 'yaml'  
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app_config.yml', __FILE__)))[Rails.env]
```

Then access the constant globally:

```
APP_CONFIG['site_url']
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the way your yml file is formatted, the resulting parsed hash looks like this:

```
{"development"=>{"site_url"=>"http://localhost:3000"}}
```

The indent in the second line makes the 'site_url' hierarchically fall inside 'development'. In addition, they aren't directly accessible via symbols.

So accessing site_url the way you have the yml formatted would be

```
APP_CONFIG['development']['site_url']
```